# Does storyboard replace .xib file in Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode

Have started playing with Xcode 4.2, and created a single page application using storyboard and ARC. When I opened up the file, there are five files: AppDelegate .h and .m and ViewController .h, .m and storyboard.

No .xib file.

Is this normal? Or do I need to do something to generate a .xib file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is normal. Storyboards eliminate the need for seperate `.xibs`. Be advised that using storyboards means you can NOT target devices running any iOS below 5.0. If this is important to you, like it is to me, then create your projects with the 'Use Storyboard' unchecked.

[image: Uncheck "Use Storyboard" when creating a project]